# Different session IDs between http and https php

Tags: php, http, session, https

In a PHP environment, is it possible to have different/independent sessions while using http and https?

I want to use https on my site just for administration purposes, but, once the rest of the site is http, using https gets useless if I use both at the same time.

Comment: Set the session cookie established in the HTTPS section as 'secure-only', so it'll only get transmitted via HTTPS. That'll keep the "secure" session from leaking out into the insecure side of things.

Comment: Another option would be to put the administration on a different subdomain to the main site.

Comment: Marc - Thank you but, how do I do that? I just use "session_start()", I checked the documentation and I found nothing to control it.
Treffynnon - I use different domains on my site and all of them have the same sessions (and I want it in that way). Seems I misunderstood your idea. Thank you btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different session cookie params based on URI.

[session_set_cookie_params](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)

Comment: Exactly, I was now rechecking the documentation, and found this some seconds ago :) - I'll accept this answer! Thank you.